# Differences between rand in SAS and rgamma/rpois in R for data generation?

Tags: r, statistics, sas, simulation, correlation

I am having an issue getting similar results when generating data from distributions using R and SAS.

Basically, my goal is to simulate correlated negative binomial data using a special case of Molenbergh, Kalema, and Iddi's 2nd Algorithm (the combined model), which involves introducing correlation (within each observation) and dispersion through gamma random effects and then generating the correlated data from a Poisson distribution (with lambda being the desired mean * gamma random effects). This achieves a Poisson-Gamma mixture model, from which the negative binomial is derived. Then, I plan to use this data to make an empirical power calculation (by splitting the generated data into reps, fitting each rep to a NB model using PROC GENMOD, comparing the upper bound on a 95% CI for the LS-mean differences to a set boundary for each, calculate proportion where boundary is not in CI).

When making this power calculation, I am noticing that the 95% confidence intervals are generally wider when using the correlated data generated by the R code. For example, with 1500 reps, the mean interval size is 1.01 in R, and 0.9 in SAS. This makes the null hypothesis harder to reject, leading to less power. For example, for a particular sample size I am interested in, the power is 81% using the data generated in R, compared to 89% using SAS. In my opinion, this is too large of a difference. I am using rgamma and rpois in R, and rand('Gamma') and rand('Poisson') in SAS.

I have checked my code between R and SAS, and all the formulas I used to simulate the data are the exact same. I also reviewed the means and variances for the gamma random effects and correlated NB data, and when increasing N the means converge to the desired means in both R and SAS, and the variances converge to roughly the same value.

The code I am using to calculate power after generating the data is the exact same SAS code for both programs, so I know the discrepancy is due to the data generation, but I am unsure what could be causing it. Maybe there are some more extreme values generated from the R code that are causing this, but I really have no idea, as the variances are equal between programs. I assume that rgamma and rand may utilize different algorithms to obtain results, but since the parameters are the exact same shouldn't the results still be very similar? I am just looking for some additional troubleshooting tips to figure out which one of my programs is more accurate, and more ideally, to get the two program results to match more closely.

Code for generating the data:
SAS Code (within a macro, there may be a more efficient way to do this but I'm relatively new to SAS):

```
%let shapex = %sysevalf(&a1 - (&min_a * &rho1));
%let shapey = %sysevalf(&a2 - (&min_a * &rho1));
%let shapez = %sysevalf(&min_a * &rho1);
* Generate independent gammas;
data gamma_gen;
    call streaminit(12345); 
    do i = 1 to &n;
        x = rand('Gamma', &shapex, 1);
        y = rand('Gamma', &shapey, 1);
        z = rand('Gamma', &shapez, 1);
    output;
end;
run;
* Obtain correlated gammas;
data corr_gamma;
    set gamma_gen;
    G1 = &b1 * (x + z);
    G2 = &b2 * (y + z);
run;

* Correlated NB;
data corr_nb;
    set corr_gamma;
    lambda1 = &m1 * G1;
    lambda2 = &m2 * G2;
    call streaminit(12345);
    V1 = rand('Poisson', lambda1);
    V2 = rand('Poisson', lambda2);
    drop i x y z G1 G2 lambda1 lambda2;
run;
```

R Code (rNB generates data):

```
rG = function(N, a, b, rho) {
  rho1 = rho * sqrt(max(a)/min(a))
  if (rho1 > 1) return(NA)
  else {
    X = rgamma(n = N, shape = a[1] - min(a) * rho1, scale = 1)
    Y = rgamma(n = N, shape = a[2] - min(a) * rho1, scale = 1)
    Z = rgamma(n = N, shape = min(a) * rho1, scale = 1)
    cbind(b[1] * (X + Z), b[2] * (Y + Z))
  }
}
rNB = function(N, k, m, r) {
  rho = getrho(k,m,r) # this value is the exact same between both programs
  gamma_sample = rG(N, 1/k, k, rho)
  if (!any(is.na(gamma_sample))){
    return(cbind(rpois(n = N, lambda = m[1] * gamma_sample[,1]),
                 rpois(n = N, lambda = m[2] * gamma_sample[,2])))
  }
}
```

Comment: correct if I'm wrong, but both of these are random processes. Why would you expect the numbers to be identical?

Comment: Export data generated by SAS rand and compute it with R, to find where does the difference comes from, the data in different software or other computation program in different software.

Comment: Share some code. How do you expect people to be able to help without that? I wouldn't be surprised if you have misunderstood documentation regarding function parameters.

Comment: Agree, a difference that large between R and SAS sounds like something is going wrong.  Instead of focusing on the random number generation, I would focus on the statistical calculations.  Easiest way to do that would be to simulate a dataset from R and export it to a CSV, and simulate a dataset from SAS and export it. So you have Rsim.csv and SASsim.csv, as fixed input.  Now process both files in both R and SAS, and see how your results compare. I expect you'll find differences.

Comment: @Mark I expect there to be slight differences, but I don't think a difference in power that large after 1500 reps should exist. I have also ran each program with multiple seeds and there is consistently a 6-8% difference in power between the two.

Comment: @Roland  I understand that could be helpful. I added code for both programs (not the entirety, just the specific portions where the data are generated, which is where I suspect the discrepancy lies)